# How to print count value of two different entries form single column on tooltip in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, count, tooltip, row, expression

I'm stuck on a point to pass an expression to count number of male and female members.
I'm using India map .shp file where i want to print on tool-tip with Name of the state and separate count of male and female.Like **"State:- Delhi, Male:- 23454, Female:- 45454.** But i'm not getting right expression for that how i can do that. In my database there is column Gender where Male & Female entries are there row wise.

Please help me out.

Thank you.

100ROV

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like the following expression for your **Tooltip**?

```
="State:- " & Fields!State.Value
  & ", Male:- " & CStr(Sum(IIf(Fields!Gender.Value = "M", 1, 0)))
  & ", Female:- " & CStr(Sum(IIf(Fields!Gender.Value = "F", 1, 0)))
```

This assumes there are fields called `State` and `Gender`.